# How Do I Fix this Sequelize Database Error when trying to do a POST method?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I am using Postman to test a POST route for my React application using Sequelize, node and express. I am getting this error below

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "code": "ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD",
        "errno": 1364,
        "sqlState": "HY000",
        "sqlMessage": "Field 'title' doesn't have a default value",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO `Trips` (`id`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?);",
        "parameters": [
            "2019-12-01 00:50:42",
            "2019-12-01 00:50:42"
        ]
    },
    "original": {
        "code": "ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD",
        "errno": 1364,
        "sqlState": "HY000",
        "sqlMessage": "Field 'title' doesn't have a default value",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO `Trips` (`id`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?);",
        "parameters": [
            "2019-12-01 00:50:42",
            "2019-12-01 00:50:42"
        ]
    },
    "sql": "INSERT INTO `Trips` (`id`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?);",
    "parameters": [
        "2019-12-01 00:50:42",
        "2019-12-01 00:50:42"
    ]
}
```

The schema for my table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Trips (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  location varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  Description varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  tripDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  image varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  createdAt timestamp default current_timestamp,
  updatedAt timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I tried changing the various columns to be DEFAULT NULL but even when I input data into those fields, I am getting back null in the database. I added images of my code.

React Form
[image: React Form]

Trips Controller
[image: Trips Controller]

Trips Model
[image: Trips Model]

Trips Router
[image: Trips Router]

-Sam

Comment: I'd say it has something to do with the error message "Field 'title' doesn't have a default value" - I can see from your insert statement you're not giving a value for the `title` field, and I can see from the schema that it has no default and is `NOT NULL`. You need to either give it a default, make it nullable, or provide it. If you think you _are_ providing a value for the `title` column then you need to show the relevant code.

Comment: So I did try providing it at a value here in Postman https://screencast.com/t/EVatPwcgEzV . So I am guessing my code is set up wrong where it can't grab the value from the specific fields?

Comment: I don't know if express is smart enough to handle it, but what you have there isn't valid JSON. You must use double quotes, not single quotes. The dropdown that says "text" next to "GraphQL" can be changed to "JSON (application/json)" and it should highlight any problems with your JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems:

1) At your SQL declaration and in your model declaration you're missing the default value for the `title` column.

Your SQL table declaration should like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Trips (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, -- Or any other default value
  location varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  Description varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  tripDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  image varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  createdAt timestamp default current_timestamp,
  updatedAt timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

According to this declaration your model declaration should be:

```
const Trips = sequelize.define('Trips', {
    title: { 
             type: DataTypes.STRING,
             defaultValue: null // or whatever you would like
    },
    location:DataTypes.STRING,
    Description:DataTypes.STRING,
    tripDate:DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    image:DataTypes.STRING
  },
```

If you still get this error after modifiying these two your problem is on the client 
   side, for some reason the title data doesn't pass to the server and therefore is 
   undefined at req.body

Answer (score 1):

1.by default it will look for createdAt,updatedAt in your model schema.
so either you add the createdAt,updatedAt else if you don't want these 2 fields then set timestamps:false in model schema.

2.you should add id field in your model schema because sequelize always    require a id field with primary key in your model schema.Its necessary in every model.

```
 const Trips = sequelize.define('Trips',{
id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  title:DataTypes.STRING,
  location:DataTypes.STRING,
  Description:DataTypes.STRING,
  tripDate:DataTypes.DATEONLY,
  image:DataTypes.STRING
  },
 {timestamps:false});
```